# What is a quasi F ratio and how to compute it in R?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I've been reading [this classic study (free pdf)](http://e.dyffrynaman.org/psychology/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2014/01/Reconstruction_Automobile_Destruction.pdf) of false memories by Loftus & Palmer (1974) and do not understand their analysis in Experiment 1 (p. 586), particularly—

a) the use of subjects as a random effect (there were only groups defined by verbs and films and those were already included in the model),

b) the meaning of the ‘quasi F ratio’, and

c) how they could have 55 degrees of freedom with just 45 measurements.

**Could you please explain their procedure and show how to perform this analysis in R?** (I am obviously not a statistician so the simpler explanation, the better.)

You can grab simulated data [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cc9e9d371e04b309e81b127cb3d69526).

**Reference**

> Loftus, E. F., & Palmer, J. C. (1974). Reconstruction of automobile
>   destruction: An example of the interaction between language and
>   memory. Journal of verbal learning and verbal behavior, 13(5),
>   585-589.

Comment: have you tried going back to read the [Clark 1973 "language-as-fixed-effect fallacy" paper](http://journals1.scholarsportal.info/details/00225371/v12i0004/335_tlfacolsipr.xml) that Loftus and Palmer cite ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Not yet, to be honest. I'm going to give it a try when I have time tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quasi F-ratio (F') is a scoring method used when there is no single error term appropriate in the analysis.  Instead, the error term is estimate by either adding or subtracting the mean square of the factors in your analysis (precisely how this is done will depend on your analysis).  This procedure is typically used when you want to estimate the F-value when you are missing cells from your analysis - for example, if a factor in your analysis is a Likert-type rating (e.g., 1-5) and participants did not use every rating in the scale.

You can calculate the quasi F-ratio in R using the quasiF.fnc() library.